# Adding multiple columns randomly to a dataframe from columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, random

I've looked everywhere but can't find a solution.

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Year
1
2
3
4
```

and

```
ID  Value
1    10
2    50
3    25
4    20
5    40
```

I need to pick randomly from *both columns* of the 2nd table to add to the first table - so if ID=3 is picked randomly as a column to add to the first table, I also add Value=25 i.e. end up with something like:

```
Year  ID  Value
1     3     25
2     1     10
3     1     10
4     5     40
5     2     50
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, do you want?

```
df_year[['ID', 'Value']] = df_id.sample(n=len(df_year), replace=True).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   Year  ID  Value
0     1   4     20
1     2   4     20
2     3   2     50
3     4   3     25
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks for helping out an amateur !